# BUILD_BYPRODUCTS and dependency cycle for cmake + ninja + googletest + ExternalProject_Add

Tags: cmake, googletest, ninja

Attempting to use external project to build google test like so.

```
   # Add googletest
ExternalProject_Add( googletest
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git

    # We don't need to run update command. Takes time
    # and the version we initially d/l will shoudl be fine
    CMAKE_ARGS = "-Dgtest_disable_pthreads=1"

    # Don't run update
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""

    # Disable install step
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""

   # BUILD_BYPRODUCTS googletest-prefix/src/googletest-stamp/googletest-gitinfo.txt
   # BUILD_BYPRODUCTS googletest-prefix/tmp/googletest-cfgcmd.txt
    BUILD_BYPRODUCTS "googletest-prefix/src/googletest-build/googlemock/libgmock_main.a"
    )
# Get include dirs for googletest framework
ExternalProject_Get_Property(googletest source_dir)
set(GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS
   ${source_dir}/googlemock/include
   ${source_dir}/googletest/include
   )

# Create library target for gmock main, which is used to create
# test executables
ExternalProject_Get_Property(googletest binary_dir)
set(GTEST_LIBRARY_PATH ${binary_dir}/googlemock/libgmock_main.a)
set(GTEST_LIBRARY gmock_main)
add_library(${GTEST_LIBRARY} UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET ${GTEST_LIBRARY} PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${GTEST_LIBRARY_PATH})
add_dependencies(${GTEST_LIBRARY} googletest)
```

With the ninja generator I get the below warning.

```
 Policy CMP0058 is not set: Ninja requires custom command byproducts to be
  explicit.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0058" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  This project specifies custom command DEPENDS on files in the build tree
  that are not specified as the OUTPUT or BYPRODUCTS of any
  add_custom_command or add_custom_target:

   googletest-prefix/src/googletest-stamp/googletest-gitinfo.txt
   googletest-prefix/tmp/googletest-cfgcmd.txt

  For compatibility with versions of CMake that did not have the BYPRODUCTS
  option, CMake is generating phony rules for such files to convince 'ninja'
  to build.

  Project authors should add the missing BYPRODUCTS or OUTPUT options to the
  custom commands that produce these files.
```

If I oblige the request of the cmake error by uncommenting the build byproducts lines in my external project command, I get a cyclical dependency error. However, if I leave the build byproducts out of it, the project seems to build just fine.

```
$ ninja
ninja: error: dependency cycle: googletest-prefix/src/googletest-stamp/googletest-configure -> googletest-prefix/tmp/googletest-cfgcmd.txt -> googletest-prefix/src/googletest-stamp/googletest-configure
```

I'm using cmake 3.4, ninja 1.6, and running on Windows using MSYS2 package.

Comment: Looks like a problem in CMake: given files are used with `DEPEND` option somewhere at download/update stages of ExternalProject (internally). But these files are created in `configure_file()` and `file(WRITE)` commands. Because `BYPRODUCTS` option is applicable only to `add_custom_command`/`add_custom_target`, it cannot be used here. And CMake has no other way for (clearly) express, that given files are generated somewhere. You are free to fill a bug on CMake, information you provided is sufficient.

Comment: You can bypass this whole issue by just downloading GoogleTest at CMake time and adding it directly to your build with `add_subdirectory()` as explained [here](http://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/). The approach discussed there will also make your use of GoogleTest platform independent and you won't need to hard-code the library name and location like in your example.

Comment: @CraigScott: Blogbost you refer to uses `ExternalProject_Add` via `execute_process`. But, if `ExternalProject_Add` is actually bugged, this doesn't resolve problem with warnings from ninja generator. The warning will just be generated at `execute_process` time.

Comment: No it is different. Only the download is done by ExternalProject_Add. The CMake target is created directly via add_subdirectory. I use that technique with Ninja and haven't seen the problems described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I added cmake_policy(SET CMP0058 NEW) to my toplevel CMakeLists.txt file as the --help-policy text explains to. It no longer generates the warnings afterwards. I guess those files aren't needed. Not sure how they're getting picked up as dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like in ExternalProject_Add function:

```
        set(GMOCK_FILE_DIR "gmock-${GMOCK_VERSION}/src/googletest_github-build/googlemock/")
        BUILD_BYPRODUCTS "${GMOCK_FILE_DIR}gtest/libgtest_main.a"
        BUILD_BYPRODUCTS "${GMOCK_FILE_DIR}gtest/libgtest.a"
        BUILD_BYPRODUCTS "${GMOCK_FILE_DIR}libgmock_main.a"
        BUILD_BYPRODUCTS "${GMOCK_FILE_DIR}libgmock.a"
```